# Set-and-swipe Forms using Android Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, swipe-gesture

I am trying to develop a very simple Android app for rapid data collection, where an activity displays a fragment containing a form with a number of RadioGroup elements.  I would like to have the user be able to quickly tap out the radio selections, then be able to swipe the form to the right to dispose of the fragment, record the data, and bring up another empty form.

What I can't figure out is how to set up the "swipe and replace" feature.  I'm thinking of something similar to the ViewPager support class, except no scrolling backwards and an unlimited number of pages.  What classes can I use to achieve this kind of behavior?  Here's my stripped-down code:

**fragment_record.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Group 1"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/Group1">

            <!-- Radio Buttons /-->
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Group 2"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/Group2">

            <!-- Radio Buttons /-->
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**RecordFragment.java:**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class RecordFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_record, container, false);
        return view;
    }

}
```

**activity_record.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container" >
</FrameLayout>
```

**RecordActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class RecordActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_record);

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) return;
            RecordFragment theFragment = new RecordFragment();
            theFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, theFragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the simple answer to this was delivered obiter dicta in the tech talk a month or two ago where Google showed the preview of Android Studio 2.0. One of the presenters said 'we see a lot of people out there using Fragments in places where they should be using ViewGroups.' I was one of those people too.

A wizard is a complex problem: you are usually building something incrementally, so there is state, dependencies, and flow. It's hard to make really generic because what is being built is completely different. Also, it's a clear anti pattern to partially construct the target object leaving a bunch of nullable fields to be filled in as the process grinds on.

If each group can contain a part, then you can assemble the parts and build the target from the parts. There's no shame in it if those parts are not necessarily organic domain objects: if you are modeling the process of obtaining a job, there can be an Application (the thing the user has to fill out) and the CV or Submission (what is built in the form to represent a specific request for consideration).

Comment: It's not a wizard, really.  Every page contains an independent set of data that could be represented as a record in a database table.  Every time a page is swiped, the independent record is saved and the user gets a new form to submit a new record.  Nothing is sequentially linked and the number of forms the user can fill out is unknown at runtime.

Comment: That makes it even easier: for sure atomic items should not be in fragments. That's the main point the guy was making.

Comment: Okay, so fragments are wrong for this, and I should use ViewGroups instead.  That's a start, but it doesn't solve my gesture sweep problem.